# swift iOS is there a fast way to populate a realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I decided to try [realm](http://www.realm.io)

In my app users can select a category and a sub-category (one-to-many) and I decided to get the data from realm.

Right now I have my relational data in a sql file.

But is there a way to populate a realm database? I can't really see anything in the docs.

And also, is it a bad idea to use realm for read-only?

Comment: If I were you, I'd stick to something more popular, like Parse, and no I don't work for Parse, but they are backed by a lot of money, a ton of coders use them, and there's lots of answers about how to do X, Y, or Z if you get stuck. What you described that you app should do can be handled by Parse, unless of course your app is actually doing something A LOT more detailed than what you have described.

Comment: @Larcerax I only want to save the data that should be displayed in lists around my app. I thought Parse only was used as backend? I have built my own backend/RestAPI

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pre-populated Realm file that you either ship with your app or download on the fly, or you can parse the responses from your REST API into objects that can be added to the Realm.